# Do i need separate eclipse projects to develop for Android with PC agent

Tags: java, android, windows, eclipse

I am writing an Android app that will communicate with the PC.  I tried to create 2 packages in a single eclipse project, but this doesn't seem to work.  When i try to debug the PC java application, it crashes with "Cannot connect to VM".  I searched for this, and found suggestions to turn of the Windows Firewall and reboot.  This did not work.  The crash report 
states:

```
# Internal Error (classFileParser.cpp:3494), pid=4408, tid=4776
# Error: ShouldNotReachHere()
```

Maybe there is a best practice that I am missing?  Should these two similar code units (they share some common classes) be in separate projects, or am I taking a good approach, and just running into some configuration problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to have both projects in one eclipse project, you have to do the following:

1. create a run confguration for your PC project (Run -> Run configurations -> add)
2. set the JRE to any JavaSE (1.7 for example) (tab JRE)
3. remove Androidx.x library vom Bootstrap Entries (tab Classpath)

now you should be able to run your pc project.

--- edit:

regarding your question about best practice. I think you probably should have to separate projects unless your PC project is really small (like only one class)

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what will work.  I am now able to launch both applications from the same project.  Perhaps this ended up being a two part question, so regarding best practices, i will try to search on that part for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like having two separate projects will be the way to go for you.  Organizationally, I believe this will work better.  This may also help you to avoid issues like these in the future.

Comment: Would you then say that the workspace would be a better top level container?  Is there a resource that describes a best practice for project organization of this sort, or even generically?